# How to use jQuery to select a class name that's transformed by css-loader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webpack, css-loader

I'm using webpack with css-loader. Everything has been working fine except that I don't know how to use jQuery to select a css-loader transformed class. The transformed class name looks something like this "src-styleauthTextboxLeft1Npf4" with the following css-loader configuration:

```
css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path][name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
```

Here's the React code

```
const Auth = (props) => {
  const toggle = (event) => {
    // Working example
    $('#container').css('background', 'blue');

    // Not working
    $(styleCSS.container).css('background', 'green');
  };
  return (
    <div id="container" className={styleCSS.container} onClick={toggle} />
  );
};
```

Is there anyway to make the make the second selection works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `styleCSS.container` is a class, you would just need to add a `.` in front of it. Try this:

`$('.' + styleCSS.container).css('background', 'green');`

Comment: It didn't work. The compiled code is like this: "(0, _jquery2.default)('.' + _style2.default.authTextboxMask).css('background', 'blue');". It seems like css-loader doesn't transform class in js code

Comment: Can you console.log(styleCSS.container) and tell me the output?

Comment: Oh. It work! It is the transformed name. I logged the wrong class before. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Not sure if I helped but no problem!

Comment: Your solution is the correct solution. It's just that I put in the wrong classname the first time when I tried your solution so it didn't work. Now everything is fine!